# Convert SQL query to HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, select, pagination, hql

I have a sql statement as follows,

```
select *
from (select distinct field1
from X
where field2 = 'value2'
and field3 > 'value3'
and field4 in(value4)
and field5 in(value5)
and field6 is null 
order by field1)
where ROWNUM <= 20 ;
```

I tried to convert it to HQL as follows,

```
 DetachedCriteria detachedQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(X.class)
     .setProjection(Projections.property("field1"))
     .add(Restrictions.eq("field2",value2))  
     .add(Restrictions.gt("field1", value1))
     .add(Restrictions.in("field3",value3))
     .add(Restrictions.in("field4", value4))
     .add(Restrictions.isNull("field5"))
     .addOrder(Order.asc("field1"));

     Criteria criteria= session.createCriteria(X.class);
     criteria.add(Property.forName("field1")
         .in(detachedQuery))
         .setMaxResults(20);
```

Am i correct?.

Comment: You can see for yourself using the show-sql property in hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Can you bit elaborate on that?.I'm new to hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not requesting a distinct projection, and you can't just go `.in(subquery)` you have to use the `Subqueries` class, other than that it looks ok.

```
 DetachedCriteria detachedQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(X.class)
 .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("field1")))
 .add(Restrictions.eq("field2",value2))  
 .add(Restrictions.gt("field1", value1))
 .add(Restrictions.in("field3",value3))
 .add(Restrictions.in("field4", value4))
 .add(Restrictions.isNull("field5"))
 .addOrder(Order.asc("field1");

 Criteria criteria= session.createCriteria(X.class);
 criteria.add(Property.forName("field1")
     .in(detachedQuery))
     .setMaxResults(20);
```

Comment: What does criteria.add(Property.forName("field1")
     .add(Subqueries.in(detachedQuery))
     .setMaxResults(20); will do ? .I mean will it filter out the field1 alone?

Comment: `.add(Subqueries.in(detachedQuery)` will do your subselect for you. Its the `Projections.distinct(Projections.property("field1")))` will do the `select distinct`

Comment: Subqueries.in() takes in 2 params right? (object,detachedCriteria) ?

Comment: Then your query is wrong , criteria.add(Property.forName("field1")
     .add(Subqueries.in(detachedQuery))
     .setMaxResults(20); Please edit it with correct syntax.

Comment: Sorry crossed purposes code there. I was assuming you were using your subquery to restrict your set, but you're using it for everything, and only want to set the max results. Updated

Comment: So what would be the output?.Only a list of distinct "field1" values with number of entries restricted to page size?.or it would be list of X.class objects ?

Comment: It should be a list of X.class objects that match your restrictions upto 20

Comment: Then why do we need this ? criteria.add(Property.forName("field1") ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure its to set the max results, like you are doing in your code. I've never manipulated the number of results returned from a query, so you are on your own for that one

Comment: In this query , criteria.add(Property.forName("field1")
     .in(detachedQuery))
     .setMaxResults(20); we use setMaxResults to restrict number of rows , but i'm not clear why do we need criteria.add(Property.forName("field1")... Since the outer query is just used to restrict the number of rows,do we need that?Property.forName("field1").in(subquery) checks for that property in the subquery right?

Comment: Your best bet would be to try both and see what you get out. If it throws an exception, then try removing it, if you get more than 20 results your `maxResults()` isn't working